# Rails Password-only Login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, passwords

What is the best way to password protect a view? I already am generating a password but I don't want a username and password login, just the password. I have the password being stored currently as a attribute in the File class, and was using this:

```
before_filter :restrict, :only => :show    

authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |password|
  password == @file.password
end
```

However, it still prompts the user for a username and doesn't log in correctly because it is missing a username. Is there a way to use this method and only have the prompt ask for the password only? If not what is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: can you try directly without file? just for a short test: http_basic_authenticate_with :password => "foo"...same result?

Comment: for reasons I don't fully understand when setting the password manually to "test" I can't access the view unless I have "test" in both the username and password.

Right now I am looking into finding a popup dialogue to ask for the password and then verify. Know any good gems that render popups (might just be doing it in Javascript though)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic is implemented using HTTP Basic Auth that requires combination of username and password to be entered. If you want to enable password only authentication, you will have to write your own authentication method

```
before_filter :restrict, :only=>:show

def restrict(password)
  render :status=>401, :text=>"Unathorized" unless password == @file.password
end
```

Answer (score -4):

Why not just do a check in the beginning of the new activity (onCreate), and return to the previous activity if password is false?

something like:

```
if (password.equals(password)){
contiue activity
}else{
//return to previous tread
finish()
}
```

Comment: ohh, sh**t, Thougt it was an Android question... damn, what a way to get some good point.. *sarcasm
-I'm sorry..